# how to get the command and output logged in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

We need to log the command and its output. For example if I run the following command. I need to log it into a text file.

```
cat script.sh
find / -name sshd_config -print
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

cat log.out --should be as below

```
<server_name>$ find / -name sshd_config -print
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

If I use set-x in the script, I can log the command but it gives too much information. Is there any alternate way to use in the scripts?

Comment: You're saying this is in a script? Why do you want to log the commented out code?

Comment: I just edited, it is not commented out code.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155553/74329) and see Olivier Dulac's comment there.

Comment: Check out [`script`](http://man.cx/script) to record an interactive shell session

Comment: If you do not have terminal logging available (many gui terminals allow saving history), or don't want to use something like script, then you can set up your scripts to do it for you. You can set a logfile name in your environment, and have your script check if set before each command and provide the log output you want. (e.g. `[ -n "$MY_LOG" ] && echo "your command string" >> "$MY_LOG"` ). It is  a bit of work, but will provide a custom solution that you can turn on/off with an environment variable setting.

Comment: are you working on a script? this is very easy if so, you can define a one line function yourself with: `bash -c "$*" | tee log.out`

Answer (score 1):

I was curious and followed up: here's an `expect` script that makes a shell script look interactive:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set script [lindex $argv 0]
if { ! [file readable $script]} {
    error "cannot read $script"
}

set fid [open $script r]
set lines [split [read -nonewline $fid] \n]
close $fid

set shebang [lindex $lines 0]
if {[string match {#!*} $shebang]} {
    spawn -noecho {*}[string range $shebang 2 end]
} else {
    spawn -noecho $env(SHELL)
}

foreach line $lines { 
    # skip blank lines
    if {[string trim $line] eq ""} continue
    # skip comments
    if {[string match {#*} [string trim $line]]} continue
    send -- "$line\r" 
}

# send Ctrl-D to end shell session
send -- \x04
expect eof
```

Save as something like `interactivize`, then:

```
$ cat test.sh
date
getent passwd $USER
echo Hello World
$ interactivize test.sh
date
getent passwd $USER
echo Hello World
[myprompt]$ date
Thu Apr  9 18:29:31 EDT 2015
[myprompt]$ getent passwd $USER
jackman:x:1001:1001:Glenn Jackman:/home/jackman:/usr/local/bin/fish
[myprompt]$ echo Hello World
Hello World
[myprompt]$ exit
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to it for security audits I would have a look at [GateOne](http://liftoffsoftware.com/Products/GateOne).

It supports full recording of commands and output, for a short demo see: https://youtu.be/gnVohdlZXVY?t=3m13s

Comment: good tool, but I have to run the commands which I was asked too.